# nginx reverse proxy set request host header to be the proxied server name (domain)

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, proxy

I have a reverse proxy (nginx) behind my website.
When i inspect network on my browser in request headers Host is my nginx proxy domain. what i want is that Host request header to be equal to my website.

Comment: someone to tell if its possible or not ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's great to have you here. However, your question might benefit from some improvements. Could you provide more context and be more specific about your issue? This will help you get better responses. Please read following guide: [How To: Write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Afterwards [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77068047/edit) your post and improve it. Happy coding!